# unable to generate csv file using Classic ASP and JAVAScript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have written the following asp code to generate an csv file:

```
<%@ Language=JScript %>

<%
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

     var boCaseDetail = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset");
var strCon = "DSN=FAS";
var adForwardOnly = 3;
var adLockReadOnly = 1;
var adCmdText = 1;

     var sSqlCaseDetail = "Select objid,id_number, case2address,case_reporter2contact, case_reporter2site, x_fault_id from table_case where id_number in (" + filterFID + ") " ;

     boCaseDetail.Open(sSqlCaseDetail, strCon, adForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText);

     while(!boCaseDetail.EOF)
{
         output = boCaseDetail("x_fault_id").value + " " + cstrDelim + boCaseDetail("id_number").value + cstrDelim + "\n";

         Response.Write (output);

         boCaseDetail.MoveNext();   
}  
boCaseDetail.Close();
}

%>
```

The above script is generating an asp file on the click of a button. When the number of records fetched is less than 200, it is creating an asp file. But when the record count exceeds 200, no file is generated. Instead, the data is displayed in the web browser.

Irrespective of the record count, I need to generate a csv file(instead of .asp file) successfully. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the header to tell the browser its a downloadable file with a given file name:

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=YourFileName.csv"
```

Comment: This solution is not working and after adding this new line we are getting 'HTTP 500 internal server error'. Could you please let us know any other solution to create a .csv file from this code

Comment: probably because your sending white space to the browser before the header, note the gap between %> on line one and <% on line three, remove this gap. i.e. %><% - Headers must be the first thing returned to client.